# Listing path and data from a xml file to store in a dataframe

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xpath, elementtree

Here is a xml file :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ADD_LandIndex_001>
      <CNTROLAREA>
        <BSR>
          <status>ADD</status>
          <NOUN>LandIndex</NOUN>
          <REVISION>001</REVISION>
        </BSR>
      </CNTROLAREA>
      <DATAAREA>
        <LandIndex>
          <reportId>AMI100031</reportId>
          <requestKey>R3278458</requestKey>
          <SubmittedBy>EN4871</SubmittedBy>
          <submittedOn>2015/01/06 4:20:11 PM</submittedOn>
          <LandIndex>
            <agreementdetail>
              <agreementid>001       4860</agreementid>
              <agreementtype>NATURAL GAS</agreementtype>
              <currentstatus>
                <status>ACTIVE</status>
                <statuseffectivedate>1965/02/18</statuseffectivedate>
                <termdate>1965/02/18</termdate>
              </currentstatus>
              <designatedrepresentative></designatedrepresentative>
            </agreementdetail>
          </LandIndex>
        </LandIndex>
      </DATAAREA>
    </ADD_LandIndex_001>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to save in a dataframe : 1) the path and 2) the text of the elements corresponding to the path. To do this dataframe, I am thinking to do a dictionary to store both. So first I would like to get a dictionary like that (where I have the values associated to the corresonding path).

```
{'/Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/status': 'ADD', /Envelope/Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/NOUN: 'LandIndex',...}
```

Like that I just have to use the function `df=pd.DataFrame()` to create a dataframe that I can export in a excel sheet. I have already a part for the listing of the path, however I can not get text from those paths. I do not get how the lxml library works. I tried the function `.text()` and `text_content()` but I have an error.

Here is my code :

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

filename = 'file_try.xml'

with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    soap = f.read() 

root = etree.XML(soap.encode())    
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)


mylist_path = []
mylist_data = []
mydico = {}
mylist = []

for target in root.xpath('//text()'):

    if len(target.strip())>0:       
        path = tree.getpath(target.getparent()).replace('SOAP-ENV:','')
        mydico[path] = target.text()

        mylist_path.append(path)
        mylist_data.append(target.text())
        mylist.append(mydico)

df=pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.to_excel("data_xml.xlsx") 

print(mylist_path)
print(mylist_data)
```

Thank you for the help !

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what your desired dataframe looks like?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting, did you get my question, I do not know if it is clear ? thank you

Comment: Why do you need a data frame for one row of values? Why not maintain a dictionary?

Comment: No, I'm not sure I understand the question. That's why I'm asking to see your expected output/dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your interest ! I need to export all this data in a excel sheet, it is why I want a Dataframe.

Comment: hi @JackFleeting ! I try to re-edit it, I want a dictionary like the one on the question as output because it is easy to get a dataframe from it. What do you think ?

Thank you ! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of traversing XML tree. For this purpose recursive function will be needed. Fortunately lxml provides all functionality for this.

```
from lxml import etree as et
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

d = defaultdict(list)
root = et.fromstring(xml)
tree = et.ElementTree(root)

def traverse(el, d):
    if len(list(el)) > 0:
        for child in el:
            traverse(child, d)
    else:
      if el.text is not None:
        d[tree.getelementpath(el)].append(el.text)

traverse(root, d)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.head()
```

Output:

```
{
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/status': ['ADD'],
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/NOUN': ['LandIndex'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/CNTROLAREA/BSR/REVISION': ['001'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/reportId': ['AMI100031'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/requestKey': ['R3278458'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/SubmittedBy': ['EN4871'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/submittedOn': ['2015/01/06 4:20:11 PM'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/agreementid': ['001       4860'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/agreementtype': ['NATURAL GAS'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/status': ['ACTIVE'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/statuseffectivedate': ['1965/02/18'], 
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body/ADD_LandIndex_001/DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/agreementdetail/currentstatus/termdate': ['1965/02/18']
}
```

Please note, the dictionary `d` contains lists as values. That's because elements can be repeated in XML and otherwise last value will override previous one. If that's not the case for your particular XML, use regular dict instead of defaultdict `d = {}` and use assignment instead of appending `d[tree.getelementpath(el)] = el.text`.

The same when reading from file:

```
d = defaultdict(list)

with open('output.xml', 'rb') as file:
    root = et.parse(file).getroot()
    
tree = et.ElementTree(root)

def traverse(el, d):
    if len(list(el)) > 0:
        for child in el:
            traverse(child, d)
    else:
      if el.text is not None:
        d[tree.getelementpath(el)].append(el.text)

traverse(root, d)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you alexandra for your code and your explanation ! I think it is what I need when I see your output. But I can not get it because I don not understand how the function et.fromstring() works. Do I need to have a string as input ? 
I try with this little lines :

`filename = 'file_try.xml'

with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    xml = f.read()`

However I get an error : "ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration."

What do I need to put as input ? Thank you alexandra, have a nice day !

Comment: Added example of reading XML from file. Generally it should work also for XMLs having encoding in declaration.

Comment: Thank you ! I am so grateful for your help ! I will study your code to understand it, and those functions from lxml that I have nerver used. Then I will add a line or loop to remove the namespace from the path. I tried `replace('SOAP-ENV:','')` but it does not change anything. I wish you a nice week-end 
Maicol

Comment: Hi @Alexandra Dudkina, I have done a new post because I need a different dataframe where the path are not titles, and that I can use their string. I try to adapt your code how you will see, can you check if you have time ? I will appreciate it ! Best regards

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453788/create-a-dataframe-from-a-xml-file-with-the-paths-and-the-value